# Why or why not use memset in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memset

I have a lot of memset in a program which I have to maintain. Is it a good practice in modern C++ to use memset?

Why and why not?

If not, what should be preferred to memset?

Comment: No. Use `std::fill` instead. It can be optimized to a memset where possible and will work with classes.

Comment: If you have your data types defined as class, then constructor may take care of the initialization. However, if you have treatment as raw memory bytes, then memset is the choice

Comment: @NPE Can you give an example of where memset will work and fill won't work?

Comment: @NeilKirk: While `fill()` is the preferred choice, I am sure there are corner cases where `memset()` is in some way superior. Here is one I found with a quick search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074208/stdfill-does-not-turn-into-memset-for-pod-types

Comment: @NeilKirk: Just realised my wording was a bit ambiguous. The "yes/no/maybe" bit was in response to whether using `memset()` is good practice, not in response to whether there are preferred methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

90% of the time you should use `std::fill` instead of memset. This is because `std::fill` will work correctly with classes, and it will also work when setting arrays of non-byte types to a non-zero value. For example, you can memset an array of ints to 0 but you can't memset an array of ints to 0x12345678. With `std::fill` you can.

Good compilers can optimize `std::fill` to a memset where suitable. In the cases they don't, any performance impact is likely to be negligible.

Using `std::fill` when a memset would be faster isn't dangerous. Using memset where `std::fill` should have been used is dangerous. Default to `std::fill`.

Ditto for `memcpy` and `std::copy`

Comment: What should you do the other 10% of the time? Use `memset`. If so what cases should you use `memset` instead of `std::fill`?

Comment: @Zboson I don't know, I just put that to cover my backside in case someone comes up with some weird edge case in which memset is better than fill.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, `memset()` can only possibly work with standard layout types. Even for those the values are not necessarily predictable. For example, there is no guarantee that null pointers will have all null bytes although I'm not aware of any system where null pointers don't use all null bytes.

The obvious alternative is to use constructors. For non-standard layout types using constructors is clearly the only way to get the objects properly initialized. Even for POD types there are generate constructors which do appopriate zero initialization. That said, constructors typically do not initialize any padding while `memset()` would initialize the padding. Also, there is an overhead involved to calling constructors: if many objects need to be initialized it is likely more efficient to use `memset()`. In the code I'm writing I don't really come across situations where many objects need to be initialized in bulk, i.e., the performance argument doesn't really exist for me.

Personally, I wouldn't initialize objects with `memset()` but rather use the generate constructors. To initialize sequences of objects I'm either relying on containers doing the work or on suitable use of `fill()` or `uninitialized_fill()`. In the few cases where I have seen frequent use of `memset()` to initialze objects it was always wrong, i.e., I'd consider use of `memset()` a warning sign although it can be used correctly.

So, in summary, I'd consider it bad practice and rather use the consistent approach of using suitable constructors, probably from within containers, or when necessary (e.g., when implementing something similar to `std::vector<T>` a suitable algorithm. If performance shows that it actually makes a difference and the objects being initialized are standard layout types possibly `memset()` may be a choice but I don't know as I have never been in the situation where I ended up having to initialize lots of standard layout (or POD) types.

Comment: Any comment from the user who downvoted this answer within 7 seconds? Do you really read that fast?

Comment: I realize that I didn't give the desired answer ("`memset()` is great - go with it") but I'd be interested in the reason for the downvote anyway.

Comment: You discuss well the case of constructing the objects, but what about the case you have some existing objects and want to give them a new value?

Comment: @NeilKirk More likely he's one of those who have voted to close this question and think that is reason enough to downvote answers to it. I'm upvoting.

Comment: @NeilKirk: true although I'd think it is clear that the approach would be to use the appropriate assignment, probably by way of `std::fill()` or `std::fill_n()` if it is a sequence rather than `memset()`.