# What's the fastest way to reinitialize a vector?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

What is the fastest way to reset all values for a large vector to its default values?

```
struct foo
{
  int id;
  float score;
};

std::vector<foo> large_vector(10000000);
```

The simplest way would be to create a new vector, but I guess it takes more time to reallocate memory than to reinitialize an existing one?

I have to iterate over the vector to collect non-zero scores (could be thousands or millions) before resetting it. Should I reset the structs one by one in this loop?

**Edit:**

The vector size is fixed and 'default value' means 0 for every struct member (all floats and ints).

Comment: Have you identified this as a performance bottleneck?

Comment: Reset as you iterate?

Comment: Provided your type is [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) you can [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) the whole thing.

Comment: Just call `clear()` and change it later if profiling shows an actual issue. You don't need to change the values in memory, you just need to know they're all invalid. No de- or re-allocation is required.

Comment: @François Andrieux It might be a performance bottleneck. I want to test, if it's faster without reallocation, as this happens more than 60 times / second.

Comment: @Ben You should use profiling tools to identify which parts of your code are actually taking up a lot of time instead of trying things to see if it helps. Optimizing by intuition is almost always a waste of time, the bottleneck is generally not where you expect it.

Comment: Note that `clear()` does not deallocate memory.

Comment: The point I believe François is trying to get across is, "Compared to all of the other stuff going on in the program is the cost of emptying the `vector` even noticeable?" Not much point pumping effort into a 50% improvement to 1% of the program when you could improve the sucker that is consuming 80% of the time. That said, @Useless 's comment about `clear` is quick and easy. Worth doing out of general principles. And now he's posted it as an answer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux which tools would you suggest?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No you can't. If you memset the memory to all-bits-zero, you might find that the float was a signalling nan, and that any pointers caused access-violations (I have used machines where the natural implementation would have led to latter being true.)

Comment: @Ben _"I want to test, if it's faster without reallocation"_ Do you know how big your vector will grow in advance (at least approximately)? Then `clear()` and [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) are your friends.

Comment: Profiling tools are going to be platform specific (and tool requests are off-topic anyway), but examples include gbench or other micro-benchmarks, perf, gprof, vtune, maybe the valgrind callgrind/cachegrind tools ...

Comment: @Ayxan It depends on your platform.

Comment: @François Andrieux let's just assume it's not a performance bottleneck and I'm just curious and want to learn about different ways to do it?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am interested in such tools for Windows with 64 bit Intel CPU. Would you suggest any particular one?

Comment: @Ayxan Visual Studio comes with a profiler built-in. In 2015 it's in Debug->Performance Profiler... or Alt+F2.

Comment: @MartinBonner I can't quite follow your comment. You had a platform where overwriting a signaling NaN would cause a trap?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I had a platform where `void* p; memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p)); if (p) ...` would cause a segfault.

Comment: @MartinBonner Was `nullptr` zero on that platform? It's not required to be, so you may not have initialized your pointer to `nullptr`, just zero.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Shouldn't it still allow conversion to bool though? I mean, maybe the code inside the `if` caused the segfault, but I don't think `if (p)` is allowed to segfault for "invalid" p values...

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'm expecting that it's the branch being incorrectly taken that would cause the problem. The use of "`...`" implies there is more to it than what's shown, I'm assuming it isn't just `if(p);`. I'm not sure if pointers are allowed trap values. It would surprise me, but I'm just not certain. But then you have a platform with non-zero `nullptr` and with trapping pointers. Sounds like a pathological platform designed to stress-test the language.

Comment: @MaxLanghof C says (C17:6.2.6.1.5) character types are the only types required to not have a trap representation and C++17 makes no further mention of trap representations so I guess it's possible.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: you're right: I should profile first. But in this case my intuition was right and the performance increased by almost 100%, because I resetted the vector (with memset) instead of creating a new one. I had 50% kernel CPU time before. Now the CPU is at 100% with no kernel time.

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure what you did that would cause a reallocation. Just `clear` and repopulating should not cause any memory manipulation. If `memset` works it implies that you keep hold of the original vector instance so unless you do something to explicitly reduce it's capacity. I'm curious to see what would have caused the original problem.

Comment: I have a thread pool and every thread created a new vector every time it ran a task.
Now the thread uses an external vector and reinitializes it. I did it with memset, but I guess clear()/resize() might do the job, too. I haven't checked, if there is a difference in performance yet. My original question was to find out, which different options I have to reinitialize a vector. The accepted answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to determine the fastest way you will need to run some benchmarks.

There are a number of different ways to "reinitialise" a vector:

1. Call [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), for trivial types this should be roughly equivalent to just doing `vector.size = 0`. The capacity of the vector doesn't change and no elements are deallocated. Destructors will be called on elements if they exist. As you `push_back`, `emplace_back` or `resize` the vector the old values will be overwritten.
2. Call [`assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign), e.g. `large_vector.assign( large_vector.size(), Foo() );`. This will iterate through the whole vector resetting every element to its default value. Hopefully the compiler will manage to optimise this to a memset or similar.
3. As your type is trivial, if you want to just reset every element to `0` you should be able to do a `memset`, e.g.: `memset( large_vector.data(), 0, sizeof(Foo)*large_vector.size() );`.
4. Call [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) e.g. `std::fill( large_vector.begin(), large_vector.end(), Foo() );`, this should be similar to `assign` or `memset`.

Comment: Your enumeration is missing `std::fill`, which I expect to be at least as efficient as `std::memset` (in all likelihood it’s doing the same thing in this scenario) but it’s type safe and more readable in C++ than `std::memset`. There’s an impulse to go to unsafe C functions for maximum performance but this impulse isn’t justified: Since `std::fill` has more information than `std::memset` it can always perform at least as well.

Answer (score 9):

> What's the fastest way to reinitialize a vector?

Don't.

Just record the fact that the vector has no valid entries by calling [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear).  This has the advantage of being both (probably) optimal, and guaranteed correct, and also being perfectly expressive. IMO none of the suggested alternatives should be considered unless profiling shows an actual need.

Your element type is trivial, so the linear upper-bound on complexity should in reality be constant for a decent quality implementation - there's no need to destroy each element in turn.

No memory is deallocated, or needs to be re-allocated later.

You'll just need to `push_back` or `emplace_back` when you're writing into the vector after `clear()`ing, instead of using `operator[]`.

To make this consistent with the first use, don't initialize your vector with 10000000 value-constructed elements, but use `reserve(10000000)` to pre-allocate without initialization.

eg.

```
int main() {
  vector<foo> v;
  v.reserve(10000000);

  while(keep_running) {
    use(v);
    v.clear();
  }
}

// precondition: v is empty, so
// don't access v[i] until you've done
//   v.push_back({id,score})
// at least i+1 times
void use(vector<foo> &v) {
}
```

---

Since you need to zero your elements in-place, the second fastest general-purpose solution is probably to alter the loop above to

```
  while(keep_running) {
    v.resize(10000000);
    use(v);
    v.clear();
  }
```

or alternatively to remove the `clear()` and use `fill()` to overwrite all elements in-place.

If non-zero elements are sparse, as may be the case if you're updating them based on some meaningful index, it might be faster to zero them on the fly as your main loop iterates over the vector.

Again, you really need to *profile* to find out which is better for your use case.

Comment: That does mean that the vector needs to be treated differently depending on whether it was just created (it is full of initialized elements) or retained from the previous frame (empty).

Comment: Maybe - if you use `reserve` in the first place, each usage begins with it empty and the cached allocation is a transparent optimization.

Comment: I'm not pushing back elements. I want 10M entries to be 0 after every reset.

Comment: Why? What's the difference between a zero element and one that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Useless That you can write to it at any time? On a certain level this is the same question as ["what's the difference between null and zero"](https://www.reddit.com/r/geek/comments/6128y3/amusing_example_between_0_and_null_0_on_the_left/)...

Comment: You mean, if you're keeping pointers or iterators into the vector, or you need random access by a meaningful index? I guess it must be the last one, because the first two conflict with the original "new vector" suggestion.

Comment: Think of zeroing out a mathematical vector (so you can perform vector math on it). This requires the elements to be there - you don't want to include a "if the element I want to operate on isn't there, insert it" check (or a "if the vector is empty, resize it to match my operation" check) in every arithmetic operation implementation.

Comment: The score for an ID might be updated many times in one loop. That's why I want constant access time. The number of elements receiving a score is fixed though.

Comment: Right, so you need random access based on an external index. That information could perhaps be added to the question.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the fastest way to reset all values for a large vector to its default values?

Depends on what vector in its "default values" means.

If you want to remove all elements, most efficient is `std::vector::clear`.

If you want to keep all elements in the vector but set their state, then you can use `std::fill`:

```
std::fill(large_vector.begin(), large_vector.end(), default_value);
```

---

If the element type is trivial, and the "default value" is zero<sup>†</sup>, then `std::memset` may be optimal:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(large_vector[0])>);
std::memset(large_vector.data(), 0, large_vector.size() * sizeof(large_vector[0]));
```

To verify that `std::memset` is worth the trouble, you should measure (or inspect assembly). The optimiser may do the work for you.

<sup>†</sup> Zero in the sense that all bits are unset. C++ does not guarantee that this is a representation for a zero float. It also doesn't guarantee it to be a null pointer, in case your non-minimal use case uses pointers.

Comment: If the element type is trivial, one would hope that `std::fill` is implemented as `memset` (but without the potential of messing it up). In fact, that's what [clang does](https://godbolt.org/z/gbYf7S), but (without further architectural knowledge) I doubt gcc's loop is any worse.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I would hope. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5074208/2079303) it doesn't always happen. OP of that question never told if they enabled optimisations though. But sometimes you want your debug builds to be fast too.